# Parsing a numerical string into a numerical vector with regex

Tags: regex, matlab, parsing

I have a set of numerical strings (used in filenames) which I would like to parse into a vectors

Here is an example

```
-0_01_-1_0_23_0_52_-0_25
```

Which should be parse into

```
-0.01 -1 0.23 0.52 -0.25
```

The rules are:

1. There are 5 numbers between [-1, 1]
2. Numbers are separated by '_'
3. Decimal point is replaced by '_'.
4. integer numbers {-1, 0, 1}, don't have a decimal point

How can I use regex (preferably matlab) to convert the string into a vector?
I tried some regex expression, but got stuck with dealing with the integer rule.

Comment: Your best bet is probably replacing `0_` with `0.` and then replacing all remaining `_` with spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
a = '-0_01_-1_0_23_0_52_-0_25';
a = strrep(a, '0_', '0.');
res = regexp(a, '(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)','match');
res = cellfun(@str2num, res)
```

First, replace `0_` with `0,` and then use the [`-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/iT8oog/1) regex to match the numbers only.

The regex matches an optional `-`, then 1+ digits, and then an optional substring with `,` and 1+ digits.

Comment: Your answer is almost there. I am editing with my fixes

Comment: Also, not sure what you meant in: "or split with _:
res = regexp(a, '_', 'split')
res = strsplit(a,'_')   "

Comment: Yes, sorry, have to look after my daughter, and missed the fact that the decimal separator is a dot. I removed the part that was confusing.